# What is an upper bound on $e^{-W_{-1}(c_1)}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

What is an upper bound on $e^{-W_{-1}(c_1)}$ and $e^{-W(c_1)}$, where $W$ is the Lambert W function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition of LambertW, $e^{-W(c)} = W(c)/c$.

Since you're asking about upper bounds, I presume your $c_1$ is in an interval where $W(c_1)$ or $W_{-1}(c_1)$ is real.

The principal branch $W(c_1)$ is real iff $c_1 > -1/e$, with $W(-1/e) = 1$.
$W(c)/c$ is decreasing on $[-1/e, \infty)$, with values $e$ at $-1/e$ and $1$ at $0$.

$W_{-1}(c)$ is real on $[-1/e,0)$.  $W_{-1}(c)/c$ is increasing on $[-1/e,0)$, and goes to $+\infty$ as $c \to 0-$.  It looks to me like
$W_{-1}(c)$ is between $\log(-c)$ and $2 \log(-c)$ on this interval.

Comment: So, the lower bound on $e^{-W_{-1}(c)}$ is $e^{-\log(-c)}=\frac{-1}{c}$ and the upper bound is $e^{-2\log(-c)}=\frac{1}{c^2}$? Am I right?